# Another name for a political cartoonist

Tags: single-word-requests, politics

I recall reading a chapter in my government and economics class about political cartoons. There was a particular name for people who illustrate political cartoons. I've only been able to come up with editorial cartoon and that is not the word I remember. I have googled for about 30 minutes and have been unable to come up with the answer. Does anybody know what the name for this is?

Comment: You might want to ask this over on the English Language and Usage SE.

Comment: I can't think of a specific word but **satirist** or **caricaturist** were used, but usually, these were prefaced by "political" or other qualifying adjective.

Answer (score 2):

**Caricaturist** fits and may be the word you're thinking of:

> *caricaturist*
>
> a person who creates caricatures (= humorous drawings or descriptions
> that make someone's most noticeable features even more noticeable)
>
> - A caricaturist will turn a person’s potato nose or jug ears into the dominant feature in the portrait.
> - She had to contend with aggressive newspaper caricaturists who made the most of her hairstyles.

[[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/caricaturist)]

**Satirist** also fits, but less closely as it is broader, a hypernym.

Satire is defined by [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/satire):

> *satire* [noun] [C or U]
>
> a way of criticizing people or ideas in a humorous way, especially
> in order to make a political point, or a piece of writing that uses
> this style:
>
> - political satire
> - *Her play was a biting/cruel satire on life in the 80s.*

And an example given under 'satirist' (one who writes / performs / [draws ...] satirical pieces):

> - Caricaturists and satirists appealed to their patrons, mocking the stylish servant, the well-dressed sailor, the respectable shopkeeper.

[the final example from the Cambridge English Corpus].

Comment: If its "even closer", perhaps you should lead with that as the answer?  FWIW, today's WP entry on the father of modern political cartoonists, Thomas Nast, refers to him in the first sentence as a "caricaturist and editorial cartoonist".

Answer (score -1):

A political satirist might be called a **lampoonist** or **lampooner**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lampoon) has

> **lampoon**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> Publicly criticize (someone or something) by using ridicule, irony, or sarcasm.
>
> *Punch, the satirical magazine that lampooned the establishment for more than 150 years, has closed.*